# Is Einstein notation universally applicable?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, tensors, index-notation

It gets surprisingly monotonous to write the sum symbol repeatedly, so I'm wondering if one can just swap in Einstein notation at will to avoid the monotony, assuming that the symbol that's being summed over appears exactly twice?

For example, the wiki definition of $\nabla$ uses the sum symbol:

$\nabla = \sum_{i=1}^n \vec e_i {\partial \over \partial x_i} $

Could one simply write

$\nabla = \vec e_i {\partial \over \partial x_i} $

instead, and if so, would it need to be prefaced with "Using Einstein summation notation... " or is even that necessary?

If this question is more appropriate for physics.se, I'll post it there. Math.se has more hits on the search "Einstein notation," so I thought I'd ask here first.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'll say this much: if you use it outside of physics, most people will initially be confused, and then upset. I'd avoid it in contexts outside those in which it is common.

Comment: I'm not surprised to hear that, so I'm glad to get confirmation. It's a shame because it makes so much sense, yet I can see why people don't like it since it adds in ambiguity, although I think it's a fair trade-off. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I agree this is confusing and unwelcome outside areas of physics where it’s common. I disagree that it makes a lot of sense. If $a_i\vec{e}_i$ is a sum, how would you talk about an arbitrary particular $a_i\vec{e}_i$ when you needed to? Maybe physicists never have to do that? If you multiply two sums together that both use the index $i$, you have to change one of the letters if you aren’t explicit about the sum. There are a lot of confusing consequences of this notation outside a narrow context. And mathematics often includes various different index sets in single expressions...

Comment: @SteveKass: you should write your answer in the "answer" box, so that I can upvote it :)

Comment: @HankIgoe: how would you write a single term of your sum?

Comment: One clue is that this language has found a domain in which it is efficiently used. I suspect that the fact that the language both encodes and depends on global symmetry makes it appropriate in physics (where symmetries are important aspects of physical laws). In mathematics (as the comments and answers suggest) there are contexts in which the symmetry is not taken for granted or present.

Comment: My understanding of the Einstein notation is that one only sums over repeated indices when one of them appears in the "down" position (indicating a covariant vector) and one of them appears in the "up" position (indicating a contravariant vector).  Thus, for example, the gradient of a function $f$ can be written
$$\nabla f = \vec{e}^i \partial_i f$$
where $\vec{e}^i$ denotes a unit vector in the direction of the $i$th coordinate, and $\partial_i$ indicates partial differentiation in that same direction.  But in the expression  $\vec{e_i} {\partial_i}$ summation would not be implied.

Comment: @mweiss Yes, I had forgotten about that, good point.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Whenever I've seen it used, they wouldn't generally need to refer to a specific term, for example in physics tensors.

Comment: @SteveKass It makes sense in the context of (physics) Tensors (not to be confused with mathematical Tensors).  Physics Tensors obey particular transformation laws that allow us to construct covariant equations.  This convention also has the benefit of enforcing covariance in constructions.  Your example of a specific $$a_i\vec{e}^i$$ is not covariant, so you can't use Einstein Notation to construct it (at least not in that way).  However, to avoid ambiguity, I believe the accepted notation is to underline an index to indicate that it is "fixed."

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Don’s comment this is confusing and unwelcome outside areas of physics where it’s common. I disagree that it makes a lot of sense.

If $a_i\vec{e}_i$ is a sum, how would you talk about an particular but arbitrary $a_i\vec{e}_i$ when you needed to? Maybe physicists never have to do that?

If you multiply two sums together that both use the index $i$, you have to change one of the letters if you aren’t explicit about the sum. This is likely confusing to a mathematics student. Why do you sometimes have to change letters when you multiply things, but at other times can’t?

Another problem with using this generally: mathematics often includes various different index sets in single expressions: $\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_{ij}$. It’s not easy to see when you can and when you can’t write such expressions in Einstein notation.

There are a lot of confusing consequences of this notation outside a narrow context.

[Disclaimer: I was a physics major for a while, and this notation (among other things) led me to study mathematics.]

Comment: The notation works well when the conditions it's designed to highlight, such as variables transforming as tensors, are true. Worst-case scenario, you can say when you are/n't using it (the latter hardly ever needs mentioning).

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is that this is used much more broadly than in physics and it will be read as intended by any audience that's learned [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), so I use it readily, and will only mention what it is if I suspect the audience might not know it. For example, in a math.se answer, if the questioner didn't use the notation themselves, I try not to assume they know it already. I still use it, but briefly name it (once per document ought to do, especially with the hyperlink I've included above, even though *you* didn't need an explanation).

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add few comments to the answers posted here.

First of all, I am afraid there is nothing universally accepted, especially when regarding notation. It is true however that Einstein notation alleys in almosy every scientific paper related to General Relativity and is also common in theoretical physics. In maths is more difficult to see it, but I do think most of the geometers are aware of its existence (although they might not like it).

Regarding how useful/useless it is, I would say it depends. It depends on the equations you need to write. If in your expressions repeated symbols are always adding then go ahead. You can use it even if that's not the case for all your expressions, you can just add a warning remark between brackets "(no sum)" or "(no sum over $i$)" before displaying   the exceptional ones.

For the other pathological case mentioned in a comment, I suggest two possible solutions: either the indices are clearly different (for instance of you are considering a tensor product of different spaces it is common to denote the first coordinates by $x_i$ for example and use $y_\alpha$ for the others and the reader knows the ranges of each indexing set) or in that particular case the sum is explicitly written.

Summarising, that would be the way I  suggest that you solve the possible issues:

> Throughout the text, Einstein notation will be adopted when there will be no risk of confusion. In such cases, and if nothong else is stated, he reader is intended to interpret repeated indices affected by a sum symbol, ranging over the corresponding indexing sets. In the cases where there may be a possible misunderstanding, sums will be explicitly written.